# Bug? Scheduled reminder won't dismiss

Tags: reminders

When I put a scheduled reminder with a daily repeat mode, it won't dismiss.

It keeps on showing and just changes the date to the next day.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

It will do this until you mark it as completed. Think of it this way: unlike recurring Calendar events, a new Reminder is created for **every** recurrence. They are all "nested" into each other, though, so that effect is not obvious.

For example, if I create a reminder that re-occurs every day called "water plants" it will appear normal the first day. On day two, though, unless I mark day one as "completed", it still thinks I haven't watered the flowers on Day 1, so it continues telling me that I need to water the plants on Day 1. As soon as I check Day 1, it will be marked as completed until Day 2.